# How can I send an automatic embed to a channel with an interval?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const { Client, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const Birthday = require('../../Models/Birthday');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('birthday')
    .setDescription('Saves a user\'s birthday.')
    .addUserOption(option =>
      option.setName('user')
        .setDescription('Select the user.')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('date')
        .setDescription('Select the birthdate (DD.MM.YYYY).')
        .setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction) {

    const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');
    const date = interaction.options.getString('date');

    const birthday = new Birthday({
      userId: user.id,
      birthday: date,
    });
    await birthday.save();

    await interaction.reply(`${user.username}'s birthday has been saved as ${date}.`,);

    setInterval(async () => {
    
        const today = new Date();
        const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = today.getDate();
    
    
        const users = await Birthday.find({ birthday: `${day}.${month}.` });
        const client = Client;
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1034193578450231346');
    
        for (const user of users) {
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(`Happy Birthday ${(user.userId)}!`)
            .setDescription(`Today is your birthday, ${user.birthday}! Have a great day! `)
            .setTimestamp()
    
          if (channel) {
            channel.send({ content: `<@${user.userId}>`, embeds: [embed] });
          }
        }
      }, 1000 * 60 * 1); 
    }
    
  }
```

I am trying to:

Save birthdays in a mongoDB schema and want my bot to check in an intervall if one of the dates is today, if yes, I want it to send automatically an embed message to a channel with a happy birthday message.

It saves the birthdates, but it doesn't really send the embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) would be easier than `setInterval` if you want this to run at the start of every day. Using `setInterval` in the command would only create the interval if the command were run and multiple intervals would be created if the command were run multiple times. I recommend setting it somewhere in your main file. You also can't just import `Client` from discord.js like that. [You need to construct the client in your main file and use that.](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/main-file.html)

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(async () => {
        const today = new Date();
        const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = today.getDate();
    
        const users = await Birthday.find({ birthday: `${day}.${month}.` });
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1034193578450231346');
    
        for (const user of users) {
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(`Happy Birthday ${(user.userId)}!`)
            .setDescription(`Today is your birthday, ${user.birthday}! Have a great day! `)
            .setTimestamp()
    
          if (channel) {
            channel.send({ content: `<@${user.userId}>`, embeds: [embed] });
          }
      }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 1); 
});
```